# Redefine sizes of a .pdf figure

Tags: floats, pdf, resize

I want to include some figures from Simulink (pdf file) in my thesis. However, the size of the images are usually too large and I have some extra white spaces that are quite ugly in the document. I don't have acces to acrobat to resize the pdf, and I would like to know if there is any possibility to reduce the height of the figure.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) in you LaTeX installation there is a command line tool called `pdfcrop` you can used to crop PDF files, syntax `pdfcrop file.pdf`. As for scaling you can use the `width=...` option to `\includegraphics`

Comment: The `epspdf` texlua script does an excellent cropping job.

Comment: Yes! It is perfectly explained in the other question. Sorry for the duplicity